# Differences between a bought certificate and a dev certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, certificate

I Got a solution that contains a C# winform client and a server (Windows Service WCF service, IdentityServer4 and ElasticSearch). Certificate is required when running IdentityServer in production so this will be implemented on all of the services. It will probably only be a one way certificate(function certificate for services).

The production will run a bought certificate.

**Is there any reason to buy an certificate for dev or will a dev certificate from a local Windows server be enouth to really test everything like as if it was in production?**

Comment: Isn't that exactly the purpose of development certs? (I guess you mean self-signed certificates.) To test without having to buy a "real" Certificate?

Comment: Yes, I hope so but im not sure that it will act exacly like a "real" certificate and thats why Im asking. Is there eny diffrence between a dev and a real cert becides a real is issued by a known owner(like verisign)?

Comment: Well it should roughly resemble the certificate you are going to buy: The exact type, security levels, time to expiration, ... but apart from "configuration settings" they should not be a difference in usage.

Comment: I have 4 computers(windows 10) not connected to a domain, each of them are running dev env and needs a certificate to work. Is it possible to make a self-signed certificate(Windows 2012 r2) on a server and then install and use it on these 4 computers? I am already ignoring the certificate host ip check on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A test certificate will work the same way as a bought certificate. Its however possible that you will need to override the check of the certificate on client and service to grant it even if the certificate is not installed in the required service. If you however are able to generate certificate specific for the computers that are running the software, then there will be no need to override the certificate check method.